# Expand grid in data.table by group variable efficiently

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create an expanded grid from a `data.table`. The vectors to create the expanded grid are defined by a grouping variable.

This would be my example dataset:

```r
library(data.table)
dt_sample <-
    data.table(group = c(rep("a", 4L), "b", "d"), value = LETTERS[1:6])
# example table
print(dt_sample)
#>    group value
#> 1:     a     A
#> 2:     a     B
#> 3:     a     C
#> 4:     a     D
#> 5:     b     E
#> 6:     d     F
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

```r
## I would like an automatic if possible one step approach for this
a <- dt_sample[group == "a", value]
b <- dt_sample[group == "b", value]
d <- dt_sample[group == "d", value]

final_result <- CJ(a, b, d, unique = TRUE)
# expanded grid
print(final_result)
#>    a b d
#> 1: A E F
#> 2: B E F
#> 3: C E F
#> 4: D E F
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I have thought of a few ways to do the prior, using `dcast` or a `for` loop. However, I have the feeling that it can be done more efficiently within `data.table`. Any advise is welcome.

Comment: This example seems straight-forward since the number of factors in the `a` group is a multiple of the number of factors in each of the others, but what do you think should happen if (say) `b` has three factors?

Comment: @r2evans that's the reason why I asked. MkWTF 's answer using `split` seems quite straightforward and generic. To be honest, I didn't know about the `split` function before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this with [`split`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/split) and [`do.call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/do.call):

```
do.call(CJ, split(dt_sample$value, dt_sample$group))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about the `split` function. The call can be included in the `data.table` context also `dt_sample[, do.call(CJ, split(value, group))]`